# Prevent Jackson auto convert time zone in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I using RestController in Spring Boot and I have problem with Jackson auto converting time zone. When I try to send date to RestController, the date is auto convert to my current time zone and I don't want to prevent it to happened.
If I send

```
"NGAY": "2022-07-29T17:00:00.000+00:00",
```

I want to receive

```
2022-07-29
```

no matter what the time zone is

Not

```
2022-07-30
```

This is code in model class

```
    @Column(name = "NGAY")
    private java.util.Date ngay;
```

And this is code in my RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/sanluong/ngay")
public class Controller {
    @PostMapping("/savedata")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestBody List<MLoadprofileView> lstData)  {
        ResponseData result = sanLuongNgayService.onSaveData(lstData);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
}
```

I tried in `application.properties` but it has no effect

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
spring.jackson.deserialization.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE = false
```

EDIT: I want to applied to all java.ulti.Date field in all class

Comment: try using ``@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", timezone = "GMT")``

Comment: `java.util.Date`? Really?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose what's wrong with `java.util.Date`

Comment: Oh ... Please got and put your quesion "what's wrong with java.util.Date" into the search machine of your choice. I am sure you get a hell lot of good articles. Let me tell you one: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/